# How can I resample a curve unevenly?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to resample a simple curve but with **uneven** space between the instances. If I'm using the `Length` or `Count` option, the distance between the instances is always the same. Is there a way to vary the distance between the instances by a small random factor?

I attached the screenshot of a simple example below. I want the space between the cubes to be different depending on a random factor.

[image: Curve evenly resampled]

Comment: You want this for something simple like this straight line or all curves in general?

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276888/35559) is related. Just replace the 'Power' cluster with a 'Random' cluster of your own..

Comment: Additionally to the linked answer I suggest that instead of plugging the output of the _Resample Curve_ into the _Sample Curve_ node I'd rather use the original curve. This way you make sure that even with a low resample count the instances are distributed on the curve, not slightly displaced.

Comment: And if you want to make sure the first and last instance stay on the endpoints of the curve and don't move, you can plug the _Result_ of the _Map Range_ into a _Math_ node set to _Modulo_ with 1 as the second value. Then that output into a _Compare_ node to check if it's _Greater Than_ 0. The _Result_ you can plug into _Selection_ input of the _Set Position_ node, this way only the instances between the first and last are moved along the curve.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann  MarkusVB passed on your comment.. You're absolutely right ....thanks! I've corrected the linked answer. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts You're welcome, I didn't want to edit your answer on my own and actually I thought it to be not so important in your solution, since there you have a curve that's built from those resampled points and you can see the shape. While in this case where you only have objects instanced on points that should be shifted back and forth on the curve, it might not be so obvious why some cubes seem to go astray from the path. Especially if you a smooth bending curve and maybe only want 5 instances placed along it.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for your quick answers! I want it to work on curves on general. I combined and implemented all of your ideas and it works now. I put my solution below if anyone has the same problem. Thanks!

[image: Uneven space between instances]

Comment: That's mostly as I would have done it as well. The only difference in my setup was I used a _Random Value_ going from a small negative value to a small positive value and added this to the _Map Range_ result. But multiplying is actually smarter than my idea ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,
My simple derivate of your examples.

[image]