# Geometry-Nodes: Adaptive curve subdivisions based on length

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, subdivision-surface

**What I have**:
A node system that takes in a Curve an creates mesh around it. It is thin at the start (left side) and thickens up towards the end (right)
**What i want**: I want to subdivide the curve based on the length of the curve. That means when the curve is longer, there should be more subdivisions. **But more important**: I do not want the subdivisions to be distributed evenly along the curve (like right now, marked with red) but **many subdivision at the start going to fewer towards the end** (marked with black lines, where one black line illustrates a subdivision).
I appreciate every feedback!
[image: What i want to achieve]
[image: Node System]

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276888/157965

Comment: unfortunately this did not work for me.

Comment: @Ricardo Would you mind sharing the reason it's not working for you? Because it looks like it should be doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I tried again and you were totally right. I made a mistake yesterday and since i do not fully understand what is going on behind the nodes, i thought it would not work. Thank you both and have a great day!