# more density curve on start

Tags: geometry-nodes, splines

How to make a denser curve at the start via geometry nodes?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276888/35559.. but I'm naturally biased.. :) I'll wait to see if you/others agree.

Comment: @RobinBetts yup agreed

Comment: Hi, timur.. closing this as a duplicate .. I hope that's OK. if you don't think so,  (it doesn't work for you,) edit explaining why, and we can re-open for you,