# How do I distribute more points at the end of a curve?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am using the curve to points node.
[image]
Is there a way to distribute the points along the curve so that there are more of them towards the end of the curve? Perhaps using a gradient or curve length node?
[image]

Comment: I know the search isn't that great when looking for duplicates, but this might qualify: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/276888/35559

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way to do this is this:

[image]

so just resample the curve by sample curve and gradient.

of course instead of gradient you can also use a float curve.

Here the node tree with float curve, which is easier adjustable, if you want to:

[image]